# Google Analytics how to understand Category, Action and Label for a mobile project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm implementing Google Analytics in a mobile (iOS) project and am running into an issue where I can't understand how to structure my reporting hierarchy. **How do I use Category, Action, Label for Google Analytics events?**

```
 NSMutableDictionary*event = [[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
                                                                        action:@"button_press"  // Event action (required)
                                                                         label:@"play"          // Event label
                                                                         value:nil]
                                 build];
```

I've looked at the [original iOS documentation for Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events), as well as [this web tracking example](http://www.koozai.com/blog/analytics/the-complete-google-analytics-event-tracking-guide-plus-10-amazing-examples/) and I'm still unclear on how to use events in mobile environment.

In the example above,:

- Would all of my UI events fall under `ui_action` category?
- Would all my buttons go under `button_press` action (with labels to differentiate)?
- Would my text fields edits go under `text_entry` action?
- Or do I need a unique action for each button, like `button_play, button_stop, button_buy` ?

Maybe there's a tutorial or an example project with fully defined analytics events built in that I can take a look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events reports in GA can be broken down into all your categories, all your actions, and all your labels, each in separate reports depending on which Primary Dimension you have selected. Alternatively, you can drill down into any particular event category, and find the associated action and label that were used.

In your particular example, if all your events used the category "ui_action" (although I wouldn't suggest making them all the same), then your Event Category report would only show a single entry, which would be "ui_action". The same thing goes for the action and label.

Ideally, each button, or more broadly, each event, should have a terse, yet descriptive, event category, action, and label. Similar events could have the same cateogry, action, or label, but usually you want to differentiate between buttons, that do different things, on the same page. The category is usually broadly named, like "buttons", and the action and label get more descriptive, with the label being the most descriptive, and the most populous entry in your reports.

I'm sure you probably looked here already too: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events